# Show that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) - \operatorname{Var}(X) = E[XY] - E[X^2]?$

Tags: probability

I am having trouble finding a way to solve this problem:
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) - \operatorname{Var}(X) = E[XY] - E[X^2]$$

I don't know if the left side equals the right side of equation.

for help:

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = E[XY] − E[X]E[Y]$$

$$\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$$

Comment: You can tell from what you wrote that this holds exactly if $E(X)^2=E(X)E(Y)$, that is, if $E(X)=0$ or $E(X)=E(Y)$. So it seems you're missing some premise.

Comment: What is the exact statement of the problem? Are you asked to solve this equation (so what are the unknowns)? Or are you asked to prove this equality for all X, Y? Or did you copy well the statement?

Answer (score 1):

The equality does not hold in general. We have that
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)-\operatorname{Var}X=\operatorname E[XY]-\operatorname E[X]\operatorname E[Y]-(\operatorname E[X^2]-(\operatorname E[X])^2)
$$
and the stated equality holds if and only if
$$
\operatorname EX(\operatorname EX-\operatorname EY)=0
$$
which is not true in general.